# How to make godot character Jump

Tags: godot

I am making a 3d game in godot and dont know how to make a natural looking jump, no animations just movement. I am currently just using a timer and the lerp function to make a jump it does work just it doesn't look right it seems to zippy to be a natural jump. I don't think writing a few hundred lines of code for it to change the "velocity" function from 20 to -20 smoothly

```
export var velocity = Vector3(0, -25.0, 0)
const SPEED = 20



func _ready():
    print("Working")
    

func _physics_process(delta):   
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
        velocity.y = SPEED
        var t = Timer.new()
        t.set_wait_time(0.5)
        t.set_one_shot(true)
        self.add_child(t)
        t.start()
        yield(t, "timeout")
        velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,0.0,1.0)
        t.set_wait_time(0.1)
        t.start()
        velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,-20.0,1.0)
        
        
        
        
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a little bit of a dumb question, i am new to 3d things in godot

Answer (score 0):

---

### On lerp

If I were to implement `lerp` in GDScript, it would look like this:

```
func lerp(from:float, to:float, weight:float) -> float:
    return from + (to - from)*weight
```

If you set pass a `weight` of `0.0` you get the initial value `from`. And if you pass a `weight` of `1.0` you get the final value `to`. If you were to pass a `weight` between `0.0` and `1.0` you would get a result in the between the initial and final value - and the point of `lerp` is that you would keep the initial and final values and steadily change the `weight`. *But you are not doing that.*

You are doing this:

```
velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,0.0,1.0)
```

Which means:

```
velocity.y = 0.0
```

---

Thus, this code:

```
        velocity.y = SPEED
        var t = Timer.new()
        t.set_wait_time(0.5)
        t.set_one_shot(true)
        self.add_child(t)
        t.start()
        yield(t, "timeout")
        velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,0.0,1.0)
        t.set_wait_time(0.1)
        t.start()
        velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,-20.0,1.0)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
        velocity.y = SPEED
        var t = Timer.new()
        t.set_wait_time(0.5)
        t.set_one_shot(true)
        self.add_child(t)
        t.start()
        yield(t, "timeout")
        velocity.y = 0.0
        t.set_wait_time(0.1)
        t.start()
        velocity.y = -20
```

---

### On timer

Notice that you are adding timers as children every jump (and I don't see you remove them):

```
        var t = Timer.new()
        t.set_wait_time(0.5)
        t.set_one_shot(true)
        self.add_child(t)
        t.start()
        yield(t, "timeout")
```

We can do something different, which will not have that problem, it is just one line, and it is functionally equivalent:

```
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.5), "timeout")
```

Here we are using a [`SceneTreeTimer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetreetimer.html), which will be freed after it is done.

---

So this code:

```
        velocity.y = SPEED
        var t = Timer.new()
        t.set_wait_time(0.5)
        t.set_one_shot(true)
        self.add_child(t)
        t.start()
        yield(t, "timeout")
        velocity.y = 0.0
        t.set_wait_time(0.1)
        t.start()
        velocity.y = -20
```

Is functionally equivalent to this:

```
        velocity.y = SPEED
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.5), "timeout")
        velocity.y = 0.0
        t.set_wait_time(0.1)
        t.start()
        velocity.y = -20
```

Wait, you start the timer again, but you don't wait on it? Oh, it is just this:

```
        velocity.y = SPEED
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.5), "timeout")
        velocity.y = 0.0
        velocity.y = -20
```

That is just this:

```
        velocity.y = SPEED
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.5), "timeout")
        velocity.y = -20
```

---

And hopefully that is simple enough that you can read what is going on. You set a vertical speed, wait half a second and then set another vertical speed.

---

### Back to High school

Do you remember vertical throw? We want a motion that follows this formula (with time as parameter `t`):

```
y = c + b*t + (1/2)a*t^2
```

Where:

- `a` is acceleration (gravitational)
- `b` is initial vertical velocity
- `c` is initial height

---

Oh, but Godot wants a velocity for `move_and_slide`. And we must use that so it interacts with the game physics.

Ok, no matter. We derive the formula. I mean, we use a derivation. Differential calculus… No, no, come back. Ask Wolfram|Alpha to do it: [differentiate {c + b * t + (1/2)a * t^2} with respect to t](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=differentiate+%7Bc+%2B+b+*+t+%2B+%281%2F2%29a+*+t%5E2%7D+with+respect+to+t)

We get this:

```
a * t + b
```

So that is our vertical velocity (change in height respect the change in time):

```
velocity = a*t + b
```

---

What do you mean what `time`? It is the time at which the jump began. We can store it in a varia… Look, let us compute the change in velocity `delta_velocity` after a time `delta` (you do have `delta`):

```
velocity_a = a*t + b
velocity_b = a*(t + delta) + b
delta_velocity = velocity_b - velocity_a
```

We get this:

```
delta_velocity = a * delta
```

---

### Solution

Add gravitacional acceleration, and we do this:

```
export var velocity := Vector3(0, -25.0, 0)

const SPEED := 20.0
const GRAVITY := -10.0


func _physics_process(delta):   
    var delta_velocity := GRAVITY * delta
    velocity.y += delta_velocity
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
        velocity.y = SPEED
        
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

What? It went through the floor? Well…

```
export var velocity := Vector3(0, -25.0, 0)

const SPEED := 20.0
const GRAVITY := -10.0

func _physics_process(delta):   
    move_and_slide(velocity)
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += GRAVITY * delta

    if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
        velocity.y = SPEED
```

Here I'm using `is_on_floor`, so make sure to put a solid floor for your character to stand in.

By the way, I'm going to recommend to set the physics engine to Godot Physics on Project Settings -> Physics -> 3D. That is because there is a Bullet integration bug that gives inconsistent results for `is_on_floor`. Although I don't expect it to be a problem with this code, since: 1. we are checking `is_on_floor` after `move_and_slide` and 2. we don't set the velocity back to zero when the character is on floor. However, not setting the velocity to zero will be a problem when it walks to off a ledge, since it would have stored speed.

*I'm also going to remind that you probably want coyote time and jump buffering (look it up).*

---

Wait, wait, wait. You want to make sure the jump takes a second? What gravity should it have?

We have four variables:

- How height it jumps
- How much time the jump takes
- What is the gravity
- What is the initial speed

If we know two of these, we can compute the other two. In you case, your code took half second going up, and other half second going down. So the jump lasted a second. And you have a speed constant. So we can compute the equivalent gravity and height, with time and speed:

```
var half_jump_time := 0.5
var initial_speed := SPEED
var gravity := -initial_speed / half_jump_time
var max_height := initial_speed * half_jump_time / 2.0
```

*Be careful with divisions by zero.*

If you are making a game, it will be useful for the scenario design to know how high your character can jump. But perhaps you want to make that a parameter.

We can do speed and height:

```
var max_height := HEIGHT
var initial_speed := SPEED
var half_jump_time := 2.0 * max_height / initial_speed
var gravity := -initial_speed / half_jump_time
```

Or we can do time and height:

```
var max_height := HEIGHT
var half_jump_time := 0.5
var initial_speed := 2.0 * max_height / half_jump_time
var gravity := -initial_speed / half_jump_time
```

Anyway, regardless of how you compute gravity - and if you use the jump height or not - you can plug the gravity in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that: This is a waste of time and you can make a animation. Is easier and faster but if you want to do this with the hard way I agree with Theraot!!